# how do i connect a PLL

Tags: pll

i want to sync an ac source with the grid ac. I would like to connect a Phase locked loop circuit between a grid ac source and another ac source.  I don't understand where to connect the ac source (not grid ac).

Comment: Thats ... not how this works ...

Comment: Tammara, for the next question you make, I think you need to really think, for a good 20 minutes. Think about, what you are asking about, and what information you are presenting to us. Then ask yourself if it is even possible to solve it with the information you have presented to us. - You need to step up your game at asking questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AC sync isn't PLL-controlled because we are talking about a phase difference of exactly zero **at any moment** to maintain, and a PLL cannot do this. A PLL only minimizes the phase difference over one period. This isn't good enough for power applications.

Instead, your AC inverter has to be a grid-controlled type, which doesn't have an internal frequency at all but is fully controlled by the grid phase. Such converters are very simple, you e.g. can use a bridge rectifier where you replaced each diode with a thyristor. By adjusting the firing angle of these thyristors in repect to the AC phase the grid delivers, you can transfer power from and also **into** the grid.

The bridge elements can also be e.g. MOSFETs, which has some advantages. The principle stays the same, all the control is tied to the phase the grid delivers.